# How to increase resolution of avatar rendered with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am using three.js based on HTML.
The current material is rendered using MeshPhysicalMaterial, but the resolution seems to be a bit low.

On the left is an avatar image I rendered using three.js, and on the right is an avatar image rendered using xCode from an obj file.

[image]

What material or option should I use in three.js to render good quality like the avatar on the right?

Below is the html code I used three.js.

```
<html lang='ko'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Axios를 CDN으로 사용하는 예제</title>
    <!-- axios CDN 링크 추가 -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.2/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.2/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.2/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    {% load static %}

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="loadObj()">start</button>
    <div id='myCanvas' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>

    <script>
        let scene, camera, renderer, orbitControls;

        function initThreeJS() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // 축 표시
            const axes = new THREE.AxesHelper(10);
            scene.add(axes);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.set(20, 20, 20);
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1.0);
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(document.getElementById('myCanvas').clientWidth, document.getElementById('myCanvas').clientHeight);

            document.getElementById('myCanvas').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            orbitControls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
            orbitControls.minDistance = 0.1;
            orbitControls.maxDistance = 100;
            orbitControls.autoRotate = true;
            orbitControls.autoRotateSpeed = 1.0;

            addLight(0, 50, 0, 0.7);    // 상단 빛
            addLight(0, -50, 0, 0.7);    // 하단 빛
            addLight(-50, 0, 0, 0.7);    // 왼쪽 빛
            addLight(50, 0, 0, 0.7);    // 오른쪽 빛
            addLight(0, 0, 50, 0.7);    // 전면 빛
            addLight(0, 0, -50, 0.7);    // 후면 빛

            animate();
        }

        function addLight(x, y, z, intensity) {
            // intensity: 빛 밝기 정도
            const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, intensity);
            light.position.set(x, y, z);
            scene.add(light);
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            orbitControls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }


        function loadObj(url) {
            const objUrl = "{% static 'test/TEST1-1.obj' %}"
            const mtlUrl = "{% static 'test/TEST1-1.mtl' %}"
            // MTL 파일 로드
            const mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.load(mtlUrl, (materials) => {
                materials.preload();

                // 해상도 향상에 영향 X
                // 텍스처 필터링 설정
                for (let materialName in materials.materials) {
                    let material = materials.create(materialName);
                    if (material.map) {
                        material.map.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
                        material.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
                    }

                    // MeshPhonMaterial로 변경
                    let newMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
                        map: material.map,
                        color: material.color,
                        {#roughness: 0.6,#}
                        {#metalness: 0.8,#}
                        {#clearcoat: 0.1,#}
                        {#clearcoatRoughness: 0.2,#}
                        {#reflectivity: 0.7#}
                    });
                    materials.materials[materialName] = newMaterial;        // 재질 교체
                }

                // OBJ 파일 로드
                const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
                objLoader.load(objUrl, (object) => {
                    object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
                    scene.add(object);
                })
            })
        }

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initThreeJS);
    </script>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance to the teachers who reply!